# Is it a good idea to use the timestamp as an index for loggings?

Tags: java, indexing, nosql

I use my logs to extract very useful information like:

- In this period of time how many are the users of my application  ?
- Or in this period of time, what type of services are called the most ?

Almost all the information I extract depend on the time-stamp so I wonder if it is a good idea to use it as index?

I wonder also which type of database I use to store my logs? 
I need a high performance for writing but I also need a good execution time for my analysis.

*Note that if I add time-stamp as index for 80GB, indexes size will be 12GB.*

Thanks for helping.

Comment: As Xarouma mentioned, timeseries data is best stored in cassandra or similar column oriented dbs rather on doc dbs. I'd try without index and with index for some near real time data to see how it affects my write/reads. One thing I'd keep in mind is how the size of index affects my inserts.

Comment: What do you mean by "how the size of index affects my inserts"?

Answer (score 0):

To Store your log, try cassandra !
you shouldnt use timestamp only as primary key, as you can have multiple logs at the exact same time. You can use timestamp + something else as your primary key

Comment: I don't use it as primary key but as an index.

Comment: then it will depend on which type of database you will use

Comment: Actually I use MongoDB, but I wonder if it is the best for my use case.

Comment: from what Ive learned scrolling the web, the best way to store logs is to use either elasticsearch or cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like "milliseconds since X" as a timestamp, and pad that out with leading "0"s if you want your keys to all be of the same length.

Even then, you can have a primary key collision. Depending on your logfile data, you might be able to do a form of "append" to same-timestamped data, and aggregate the different log entries under the same millisecond timestamp bucket.

Otherwise, as was said, you can add some sort of special timestamp+count to allow for multiple same-timestamped data.